# Multiple join paths in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I try to test the code example on SQLAlchemy documentation about handling multiple join paths. However after I create a customer object, both relationship attributes are None. I wonder how to properly handle multiple join paths? Do I need to create a relationship in Address class too? When do I need to use back_populates?

[Handling Multiple Join Paths](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey, String, Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    billing_address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address.id"))
    shipping_address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address.id"))

    billing_address = relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[billing_address_id])
    shipping_address = relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[shipping_address_id])

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    street = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    state = Column(String)
    zip = Column(String)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///Testing.db')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

a1 = Address(street="a street", city="a city", state="A", zip="12345")
a2 = Address(street="b street", city="b city", state="B", zip="1233")
c1 = Customer(name="Jack")
print(c1.billing_address)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationships in `Address` are not required, if you don't need them. [`back_populates=`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.back_populates) is for explicitly linking 2 relationships together, or as the docs put it, ["establish “bidirectional” behavior between each other"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html).

The reason why your customer and addresses are not linked is that you never link them. Pass the addresses to the customer during construction or set them afterwards:

```
c1 = Customer(name="Jack", billing_address=a1)
c1.shipping_address = a2
```

Now when you add `c1` to a session and commit, SQLAlchemy will handle inserting `a1`, `a2`, and `c1` in the correct order so that it can fill in the foreign key attributes of `c1`. This happens because by default a [`relationship()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) has the [`save-update`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html#save-update) cascade enabled, which places associated objects to the session as well.

Comment: Can we assign relationship like that? when I do that, I got an error: "sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: 'INSERT INTO customer (name, billing_address_id, shipping_address_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)']".

Comment: You're assigning the to-be-related object to the *foreign key attribute* directly, aren't you? Use the *relationship attribute*.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad, did not notice that. Thanks!

Comment: I have an issue pretty similiar to this, i've been able to handle the first half of the issue using the exact same method for multiple joins paths. 

However how do i cater for a relationship from address back to customer. 
As of now i can only transverse in one direction (customer to address), but not the other way round (address to customer).